# How to undelete a Google API Service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I am following this guide for deploying an API to the Google Cloud: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/quickstart-compute-engine. I successfully entered the command: "gcloud beta service-management deploy swagger.yaml", for deploying the sample API. I then deleted the service by mistake. When I try to deploy the sample API again I get this message:

"ERROR: (gcloud.beta.service-management.deploy) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Service exergo-143912.appspot.com has been deleted and will be purged after 30 days. To reuse this service, please undelete the service following https://cloud.google.com/service-management/create-delete."

I followed the instructions given on: https://cloud.google.com/service-management/create-delete for restoring the service. I used following command: "curl -d '{}' https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services/exergo-143912.appspot.com:undelete". However I get the following error message:

{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request cannot be identified with a client project. Please pass a valid API key with the request.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The create/delete doc mentions using gcurl instead of curl, which will get an OAuth token.

Please refer to the Getting Started guide to set up gcurl:
https://cloud.google.com/service-management/getting-started

If you were cleaning up and also deleted your project, you have 7 days to recover your project. After recovering your project, then you can undelete the API. If it is past the 7 days, then everything will have been purged and you will need to start over.

Comment: I setup gcurl and that fixed the problem. Thanks

I had a small issue when installing oauth2l which is required for gcurl. The guide https://cloud.google.com/service-management/getting-started says we need to create an Oauth Client Id and use it with the oauth2l. That did not work. The error message mentioned that the key has to be attached to an application. Since I did not have a working application, I replaced the Oauth Client Id with a Service account key and that fixed the problem.

Comment: Another issue was that the oauth2l was installed in /root/.local/bin, so I had to use the full path to the tool which is /root/.local/bin/oauth2l

Comment: What if I just redeploy my service? I did that, and everything shows that the service exists, yet this one command complains that it's been deleted.